# ng-upload-before-submit not getting called

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

Am using ng-upload and am trying to use both `ng-upload-before-submit` and `ng-upload-loading` on the form. But the latter gets called while the former (where I want to do some validation before the form goes for submission) doesn't. Could anyone please provide some direction please? My HTML code is below.

```
    <form id='picUpload' name='picUpload' ng-upload-before-submit="validate()" method='post' data-ng-upload-loading="submittingForm()" action='uploadProfilePic' data-ng-upload='responseCallback(content)' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      
    <fieldset class="control-group" id="username_fieldset">
        <label class="control-label" for="user_screen_name">Username</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <p class="notification" id="username_notification"></p>
            <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="user.name" maxlength="15" id="user_screen_name">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

And in my app.js am doing the following:

```
       $scope.submittingForm = function(){
         //set some flag and etc
       }

       $scope.validate = function(){
         //check if the input field is valid
          if(valid field){
            alert("checked status");
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
```

Would be grateful for any guidance here!

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Please provide a link for the directive you're using.

Comment: This is where i got ng-upload from.

Answer (score 1):

- the "ng-upload-before-submit" is wrong. it should be
  ng-**options**-upload-before-submit. (i made same mistake, following the readme file)
- inside the ng-upload i changed 2 things :

  - i update the ng-upload.js file following https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload/pull/94
  - i customized also the ng-upload.js so that the changed on scope i made during the call  of the ng-upload-before-submit corresponding function (the one inside controller) could be understand by angularjs. (these changes are good for me .. don't know if it's well done). Notice that the controller function should return true so that the apply can be called.

My few changes inside the nice ng-upload.js :

```
    if (options.beforeSubmit) {  

 var back=options.beforeSubmit(scope);  

if (back) {scope.$apply(function() {});
            }
             return back;  
           }
```

PS  : I want to thank the authors of ngUpload for their nice library.